# Отделяется ли вводное в начале присоединительного члена?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> Конечно, есть условно общие правила, например нельзя перебивать или употреблять ненормативную лексику.

Можно ли рассматривать *например нельзя перебивать или употреблять ненормативную лексику* как присоединительную конструкцию и *например* не закрывать запятой?

Будет ли правильно так расставить знаки препинания:

Конечно, есть условно общие правила, - например, нельзя перебивать или употреблять ненормативную лексику".

И объяснить так:

это сложное предложение, вводное стоит на границе частей, и, чтобы было понятно, к какой части относится оно, ставим перед ним тире.

Например, Розенталь пишет:

2) перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения и по смыслу может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей части:

Собака исчезла, — наверно, её убили.

Хотя далее приводится такое предложение:

Ср.: Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады (Пан.);

Вроде бы здесь вводное не стоит на границе частей сложного предложения.

Чем здесь является часть после тире? Может быть, пояснение к слову "куда-то"? Но тогда это пояснительная конструкция или обособленное обстоятельство места. Нужна ли в этом случае запятая после "верно": вводное ведь стоит в начале обособленного члена.

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 2):

**Конечно, есть условно общие правила, — например,  нельзя перебивать или употреблять ненормативную лексику.**

Вводное слово ***например*** позволяет нам считать эту конструкцию **присоединительной,** но присоединительным в данном случае является не оборот, а **предложение**.

То же содержание можно выразить с помощью БСП: **Конечно, есть условно общие правила: нельзя, например,  перебивать или употреблять ненормативную лексику.**

В принципе такое деление достаточно условно, но если простые предложения в составе сложного **разделены вводным словом** (***например, наверное, казалось, очевидно***), то принято говорить **о присоединительном предложении** и решать вопрос о его пунктуационном оформлении.

Розенталь раскрывает эту тему несколько уклончиво, говоря о постановке тире **при необходимости в качестве  дополнительного знака**: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

"...перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой ставится тире, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения и по смыслу может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей его частям: Собака исчезла, — наверно, её убили".

Но проще было бы сказать, что мы оформляем присоединительное предложение   по правилам вставных конструкций, то есть ставим **тире и двумя запятыми обособляем вводное слово.**